# How can I safely extract the URL in Emacs regex

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I'm having a hell of a problem reliably extracting the URL from an HTTP header using regex. It's not helped by the header alternately arriving with and without ^M characters which don't seem to match the white space class. Currently the best I've managed so far is:

```
(re-search-forward "^x-url: .*/\\{2,3\\}\\(.*\\)" nil t)
```

But of course that also picks up the ^M if it exists as well as the URL paramters which I don't really need. To give you an example from my debugging:

```
x-url: http://wiki/mediawiki/index.php?title=Vsmux&action=edit&redlink=1
x-url: http://wiki/mediawiki/index.php?title=Vsmux&action=edit&redlink=1^M
```

What I really want in both cases is just the result:

```
wiki/mediawiki/index.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like (this assumes all urls will have "://" in them):

```
(re-search-forward "^x-url: [^:]*://\\([^?\r\n]+\\).*?$")
```

Comment: Ahh I don't assume :// as file (used in my test cases) comes out as file:///. So at the moment I'm trying "^x-url: .*/\\{2,3\\}\\([^?
]+\\)"

Comment: @stsquad - but you want the leading "/" from file, so my assumption still holds.

Answer (score 3):

This looks horrible, but I'm not responsible for how it looks - people who invented this idiotic standard are... But this should follow the standard (the old version, which didn't include Unicode characters and their translation) very closely:

```
"^x-url:\\s-*\\(\\w\\|\\+\\|-\\)+://\\(\\w\\|\\-\\)+\\(\\.\\w+\\)?\\(\\/\\(%[0-9a-fA-F]\\{2\\}\\|[~\\.A-Za-z_+-]*\\)*\\)*"
```

This is unless some "helpful" program already did translation from percent-encoded URI components into their original non-encoded form.

*Also, there are some technical limits on how long the parts of the URL may be, I'm not going to try to implement that...*

*Also, it assumes that authentication scheme, like that in the basic authentication is never used. Otherwise it would be a whole lot easier to do it w/o regular expression.*

Comment: Your right about it looking horrible ;-) It's regex's like this that make me wonder if I should just be passing this off to a dedicated URL parsing function.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness I should probably add another solution I've tried based on discussion with @wvxvw about using a proper parser. This renders to elisp code looking a bit like this:

```
(save-excursion
  (let* ((url-string (url-get-url-at-point (re-search-forward "^x-url: ")))
         (url (url-generic-parse-url url-string))
         (arg-split (string-match-p "?" (url-filename url))))
    (format "%s%s" (url-host url)
        (if arg-split
            (substring (url-filename url) 0 arg-split)
          (url-filename url)))))
```